# How to rewrite this method in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following method:

```
public static dynamic ToDynamicSelectFields(this object Object, List<string> Fields)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> Expando = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor Property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Object.GetType()))
    {
        if (Fields.Contains(Property.Name)) Expando.Add(Property.Name, Property.GetValue(Object));
    }

    return (ExpandoObject) Expando;
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
class A
{
     int i;
     char c;
     string s;
}

dynamic d = A.ToDynamicSelectFields(new List<string> { "i", "c" });
```

then `d` will be a dynamic with only the `i` and `c` fields from A.

But I would like to know if it can be rewritten like this (and how to do it):

```
dynamic d = A.ToDynamic..(a => a.i && a.c);
```

because this would eliminate any possible mispellings.

Comment: Might be better asked over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How is the dynamic used? Could you get away with an anonymous object instead? `var x = new A(); var d = new {x.i, x.c};`? If you don't specifically need dynamic, it'd probably perform a lot better, and is strongly typed.

Comment: In the next stage it goes to serialization; essentially it reduces a complex object to a simpler one because it exits as a json; but it may go through a couple more stages with fields added, which is why it's a dynamic

Comment: Never used that dynamic stuff, but you may want to look into `Expression<>`.

Comment: I've never seen Expression<>, I will look, thanks!

Comment: Is the `..` following `ToDynamic` there on purpose?

Comment: The object gets modified afterwards, but it looks like I could makes a dynamic from an anonymous object and then I can be modified later on, before serialization.